# Run JavaFX with Visual Studio Code Remote Extension

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code, x11, vscode-remote

I'm already trying for a few hours to run a JavaFX application with the help of the Visual Studio Remote Development extension within a Docker Container.
I want to forward the graphic of the application with the help of X11. I already integrated the required packages for X11 in the container, set the DISPLAY environment variable and mounted the X11 socket in the container (/tmp/.X11-unix/).
Unfortunately, it won't work like that... Whenever I try to run the application, I get the following error message:

```
root@c0699153fc1c:/workspaces/JavaFX/src# java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml HelloWorldApplication.java 
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
```

I'm using openjdk:11 as base image for the docker container and installed the following packages inside of it:

- openjfx
- libx11-dev
- libxext-dev
- libxrender-dev
- libxtst-dev

I previously already tried to run IntelliJ within a Docker container, which is working fine. The GUI gets forwarded to my Display and also JavaFX applications are working fine in there.

I would appreciate any help on this matter. Maybe I oversee something.

---

EDIT:
I think I found the problem. It seems like OpenJDK:11 and OpenJFX do not work correctly, even though I followed tons of tutorials... 
So what I did now is that I exported the JDK, which comes with IntelliJ IDEA and mounted it into the container, which gets created of VS Code. After compiling the .java file with the mounted compiler and executing it, it worked flawlessly.

So now my only problem is, that I need a working setup within VS Code to get JavaFX applications working -> so a proper OpenJDK and OpenJFX configuration.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/237) might be useful.

Comment: @Boris Thanks, I already tried that before, but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the problem. So the solution was:

I created an own Dockerfile, where I took the `openjdk:12` image as base and copied the JavaFX libraries (which I got from here: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) into the container. Additionally, I added all required packages for X11 (mentioned above).
In VS Code, after the container has been started, I simply had to add the libs to the "Referenced Libraries".
Afterwards, I had to adjust the launch.json and added the following vmArgs:
`"vmArgs": "--module-path <Path-to-FX-Folder> --add-modules javafx.controls"`

Now when I run the application, the window is going to be created and shown on my DISPLAY.